# Migrate SP2010 Site Collection from one farm to another (but RBS is enabled on the source Site collection)

Tags: 2010, migration, site-collection, remote-blob-storage

How to migrate SP2010 Site Collection from one farm to another (but RBS is enabled on the source Site collection)?

I tried regular steps on moving site collections between farm but that did not work. There must be a different sets of steps to move RBS enabled Site Collection between farms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "moving site collections" you actually mean performing "Site Collection Backup" (I usually use PowerShell) and then create a new Site Collection (whatever template) followed by a Restore of the site collection backup OVER the existing Site collection (make sure at least all the dependent features, license, and farm levels are the same!), at least i've used this procedure with SQL 2008 FileStream a couple of times.

Comment: I realized Development dont have RBS client installed. So I followed MS article (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663474.aspx#Section3) on RBS setup and now it's all good. Thanks